# Do different disciplines actually require different weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, tome-of-battle

Under each different discipline in *Tome of Battle* there is a list of associated weapons. Are these weapons flavour-based, or do you actually need a weapon on the list to use stances and maneuvers of that discipline?

More info: I am building a warblade and I am interested in using the Diamond Mind and the White Raven disciplines. The disciplines' weapon lists do not share a common weapon. Will I need to change between greatsword and bastard sword in order to use the different disciplines?

Comment: Can this question be made clear (or, perhaps if I'm overlooking something, *clearer*) on how it's different from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14848/8610)?

Comment: Gonna go a step further and close this while we wait for an answer to that question. If this question is different, that’s fine—we can edit it and re-open. But if your question’s already been answered, we’d rather link anyone who finds this one to the other question and keep all the answers there. (To be clear, asking a duplicate question _is OK!_ We like having another thing people can find with searching to discover the answers they need. We just don’t want two separate questions and two separate lists of answers.)

Comment: ...I just realized you have nearly 3k rep; sorry for the basic primer on stuff you undoubtedly already knew. I had just woken up and didn’t even look to see who was asking.